# What is the most elegant way to go into a subdirectory, run a command, and come back out?

Tags: python, operating-system, glob, tar

I have the following directory structure.

```
 data
│   ├── 2019-12-11
│   └── 2019-12-12
│       ├── ADAZ19.json
│       ├── BCHZ19.json
```

I want to go in, run a tar command from os.system, and then go back out to where I started.

I tried something like below:

```
# Full filepath from root.
import os
path_to_file = 'data/2019-12-12/' # This is generated dynamically.
file = 'ADAZ19.json' # This is generated dynamically.
cur_dir = os.getcwd()
os.system(f'tar -czf {cur_dir}{path_to_file}{file}.tar.gz {cur_dir}{path_to_file}{file}')
```

Which didnt work. So now I want to go into `path_to_file`, run tar there directly on the file, then go back up to where I started. Note, `path_to_file` is set by the user and can't be hardcoded.

I want to go into the subdirectory so that the directory structure doesn't get tarred with the file. What is the most elegant way to do so?

Comment: `os.chdir(path_to_file)` ("CHangeDIRectory") and then don't add `{cur_dir}{path_to_file}` to path

Comment: @furas "I want to go into the subdirectory so that the directory structure doesn't get tarred with the file. What is the most elegant way to do so?"

Not going into path_to_file leads those directories to being tarred. I don't want that.

Comment: `os.chdir(path_to_file)` (it means `"CHangeDIRectory"`) and then don't add `{cur_dir}{path_to_file}` to path.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"CHange DIRectory"` to change folder

```
 os.chdir(folder)
```

---

```
import os

path_to_file = 'data/2019-12-12/'
file = 'ADAZ19.json'

cur_dir = os.getcwd()

os.chdir(path_to_file) # change folder

os.system(f'tar -czf {file}.tar.gz {file}')

os.chdir(cur_dir) # go back
```

---

**EDIT:** But you could use python standard module [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) to create it.

And then you don't have to chage folder but you have to use second argument in

```
add(added_file, name_in_tar_file)
```

to set name without path.

```
import tarfile

path_to_file = 'data/2019-12-12/'
file = 'ADAZ19.json'

t = tarfile.open(f'{path_to_file}{file}.tar.gz', mode='w:gz')

t.add(f'{path_to_file}{file}', file) # second argument without path to file

t.close()
```